# how can a class be changed to a function in C++?

Tags: c++, class, boost-signals2

```
template<unsigned arity, typename Signature, typename Combiner,
    typename Group, typename GroupCompare, typename SlotFunction,
    typename ExtendedSlotFunction, typename Mutex>
  class signalN;
  // partial template specialization
  template<typename Signature, typename Combiner, typename Group,
    typename GroupCompare, typename SlotFunction,
    typename ExtendedSlotFunction, typename Mutex>
  class signalN<BOOST_SIGNALS2_NUM_ARGS, Signature, Combiner, Group,
    GroupCompare, SlotFunction, ExtendedSlotFunction, Mutex> {};
```

this is a class like as defined above.
but, eclipse outline view shows this is a function.

[image]

following eclipse icon documentation, this is definitely a function.

https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_icons.htm

how can this class changed into a fucntion?

Comment: Look at the next line. Also look at the previous line and the one before that. And also on the couple of lines before that. See the pattern?

Comment: what is the next line you told?

Comment: One after the selected line in the Eclipse window.

Comment: it is just a class. i cannot see a clue that this makes signalN function.

Comment: To turn a class into a function, you have to make it a functor. Found this: [SO: C++ Functors - and their uses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/356993/7478597)

Comment: As you can plainly see, Eclipse CDT does the same thing with all Boost class templates. **It is full of bugs**. Use at your own risk.

Comment: The icon is not really a function icon. It looks very similar to one, but is not identical (larger) and is not documented. This icon is shown for forward declarations of classes and variables but not forward declarations of functions, which have their own undocumented icon.  Good luck with CDT, I think you will need it.

Comment: i understand thanks for comments